# Express JS - Redirecting If MongoDB id doesn't exist / Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

Within my Posts routes, i'm making it so that the user can go to posts/:id to retrieve information about the post with that ID, however i'm trying to make sure that if the user goes to a post that doesn't exist, he gets redirected back to the posts index route. My issue is that the server is going through the entire router.get function instead of redirecting the user and stopping.

```
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
    console.log("Test1")
    res.redirect("/")
    res.end()
  }
  console.log("Test2")
  try {
    console.log("Test3")
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
    if (post == null) res.redirect("/")
    res.render("posts/show", { post: post })
  }
  catch {
    console.log("Test4")
    res.redirect("posts/index")
    res.end()
  }
})
```

If I go to the route posts/weiqeiqwie (which isn't valid) it prints all of the test console logs. What can I do for the code to return after the error?
I'm still a bit new to using express, so sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant redirect AND render at the same time.

this is what this part of the code does when post is null :

```
    if (post == null) res.redirect("/")
    res.render("posts/show", { post: post })
```

adapt it like this, so that now when post is null it only does the redirect part.
(never forget the return)

```
    if (post == null) return res.redirect("/");
    res.render("posts/show", { post: post })
```

the same goes for the redirect line 3 :
it should be :

```
if (!mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
    console.log("Test1")
    return res.redirect("/")
}
```

also res.end() is not required. you can remove it from everywhere.

Comment: Wonderful, that worked well, I also made the code a bit shorter by removing the mongoose.isvalidobjectid statement and relying on the try catch to error handle.